# How to configure PageSpeed API to React Application for performance monitoring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagespeed, lighthouse

I want to configure Pagespeed API to React Application, where I want to check the performance of my App with both Field and Lab Data, I have heard about lighthouse but it only shows lab data, so I would want to automate it to run on every significant change/commit to checking you haven't broken something.

Answer (score 0):

There are options available in Lighthouse to automate in CI/CD , either running as a JS application (with npm lighthouse module) or as command line in your pipeline. PLease check the official documentation [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/#programmatic)

I tried them as nodejs code and it works well and creates report.